# Search ListBox Error _ Could not set the List property. Invalid property value

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I want to input data in TextBox2 for searching data in ListBox1, but it has error "Could not set the List property. Invalid property value". Debug on ".List(iii, ii - 1) = x1(i, ii)"

My code

```
Private Sub TextBox2_Change()

Dim x1, i As Long, ii As Long, iii As Integer
x1 = [myCar]


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With ListBox1
    If TextBox2 = "" Then
        .RowSource = "myCar"
    Else
        .RowSource = ""
        For i = 1 To UBound(x1, 1)
            If LCase(x1(i, 3)) Like LCase(TextBox2) & "*" Then 
                For ii = 1 To 12
                    .AddItem
                    .List(iii, ii - 1) = x1(i, ii)
                Next
                iii = iii + 1
            End If
        Next
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `x1` isn't declared. Therefore it should be a variant. It seems that `[myCar]` is meant to be a range name. If so, it might be possible to assign it to `x1` if its location were known. Perhaps your TextBox is on a worksheet and the reference actually works. Perhaps `x1` is empty from that point forward. I suggest you test.

Next you assign "MyCar" to the ListBox's RowSource property. As you know, that property holds a string. If `MyCar` is a rangename it can't be a valid range address. Perhaps something like `Range(MyCar).Address` would work. `.RowSource = "myCar"` simply assigns the word "MyCar" to the RowSource, and that should fail.
In `For i = 1 To UBound(x1, 1)` you now expect `x1` to be an array. Perhaps `x1 = [myCar]` is equivalent to `ActiveSheet.Range(MyCar).Value`. I wouldn't use that syntax but you have checked its functionality above.

Presuming that `x1` actually holds the values of a range. assigning them to the List property of the ListBox should fail if the ColumnsCount property isn't set. That isn't apparent from your code. Neither can we tell if the columns available in x1 are equal to those available in the list box or those demanded by the code.

The ListBox has rows and columns. Given that your variable i counts the rows the your variable ii should count the columns (I would use R and C to help me follow what I'm doing). Then, with rows and columns all accounted for, what does your variable iii count?

So, it is definite that there is insufficient control of the rows and columns of the ListBox in your code. However, after that has been sorted you may find that the values you wish to assign don't exist. Therefore the line that crashes your program may contain more than one mistake.

Comment: Your question lacks inforamtion. Are your controls on a worksheet or on a user form? If they are on a form, how is the form called? What is [MyCar]? If it's a range, what is its size (mention the address) and which sheet is it on - a) on the same sheet as the controls, b) on the same sheet from which a user form is called, c) on another sheet? You say you want to use a "text box input to search data in a list box". That makes no sense to me and your code is all about setting up a list box, not searching. Your question requires a major overhaul. It's too complex to explain in the comments.

Comment: I follow your advise now it is fixed Sir. Thx sir